# TOP 1 and ORDER BY not returning correct results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have read the other topics on this but they don't seem to match my scenario. I have a query that is ordering the results by Entry Date ASC and then by Sort ASC.

[image: Query Results]

The results shown are correctly ordered, however when I change my query to only pull TOP 1 it returns the second result instead.  I have no idea why or how this happens.

Comment: That is suprising. Are you able to provide a minimum reproducible example that demonstrates the issue? You could make use of [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/).

Comment: Can you _show_ your query? We can't guess how it's written but if we can see a repro we can probably determine how you got to your screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

If your query has the `order by` in the *outermost* `select`, then the results should be returned in that order. Period.

If the `order by` is anywhere else -- in a subquery or in a window frame specification -- then the results might *look* like they are ordered, but the ordering is not guaranteed.

My guess is that you don't have the explicit `order by` that the query needs to do what you intend.

Also, although not the case with your sample data, if the keys have the same value then they can appear in any order -- and in different positions when you run the query multiple times.

Comment: Yeah it was a UNION query. I have to Top 1 in the first portion of the query but I wanted TOP 1 of all the results. I realized it seconds after I posted this and was just in the process of answering my own question.